# Slow transition with D3 brush

Tags: d3.js, transition, brush

I am trying to display a financial chart with D3.js. It brings together a couple features I saw in various examples, like [brush](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367), bollinger bands, and candlesticks. The dataset has about 10.000 points. You can see the result and the code here: http://bl.ocks.org/mpaindavoine/8284597 Well, that is, ... if you're patient.

The transitions are pretty slow, to the point the graph becomes unusable. If I remove candlesticks, it's usable again.

This is probably due to the way I redraw the graph after the context has changed: I remove all the candlesticks, and redraw them.
But I can't think of another way.

Comment: The problem is the sheer number of elements. Even if you transitioned them in place it wouldn't be faster. You need to reduce the number of elements that are displayed if you want to speed it up. Using Canvas instead of SVG is another option.